# Extracting Information of some columns from a large file based on ID in the another file

Tags: linux, awk, feature-extraction

I have a large text file (about 15G) like below:

```
Chromosome  Start   Stop    Ref/Alt Identifier  Read Depth  Allele Frequencies  Het  HomoVar
1   10177   10177   -/C rs367896724 103152  0.425319    1490    320
1   10235   10235   -/A rs540431307 78015   0.00119808  6   0
1   10352   10352   -/A rs555500075 88915   0.4375  2025    83
1   10504   10505   A/T rs548419688 9632    0.000199681 1   0
1   10505   10506   C/G rs568405545 9676    0.000199681 1   0
```

I also have another text file containing subset of ID from column 5 as below:

```
rs555500075
rs548419688
```

I would like to extract the related information of columns 1, 2, 4, 5, 8 and 9 for the names within the second text file. I tried some simple grep and awk command, but didn’t work. Could you please kindly help me out with this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do this with AWK only, reading the data into a hash-table and testing if your field is in the table, but I find this heuristic *much* easier:

```sh
fgrep -wf ids.txt data.txt | awk '{ print $1, $2, $4, $5, $8, $9 }'
```

This tells grep to use the data in `ids.txt` as patterns in `data.txt`. Then, with AWK, we filter the desired columns.

Comment: You should partition `data.txt` with `split` then run this command in parallel with `xargs` on the partitions.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't much information about such things, It will be great if you kindly show me it with the appropriate command.

Answer (score 1):

With just awk:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {ids[$1]; next}
    $5 in ids {print $1, $2, $4, $5, $8, $9}
' id.file data.file
```

It will take time to process a huge file like that.

You might want to consider the awk implementation: I understand that `mawk` is quite fast: you might want to install it if it's not already there.

Comment: Thanks friend, I heard about mawk. I'll try it